# Build another page in indexedStack

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I am trying to keep my bottomnavbar same throughout the app, and I am using IndexedStack widget

```
IndexedStack(
            index: _widgetIndex,
            children: const [
              page1(),
              page2(),
              page3(),
             

            ]

          ),
```

But if there is a page inside page1 eg: page 1.1,which I navigate through page one, the bottom nav dissipares.

Comment: That's a normal behavior. Navigation makes you get to a new page and IndexedStack is for switching cached widget.

Comment: and what if I have to go to page 1.1 from page 1, keeping the bottomnavbar constant?

Comment: Do you need to replace Page1() by Page1.1() something like that?

Comment: no, just want to navigate into it, keeping the BottomNavigationBar constant throughout the app

Comment: The replacement is the best option but I've never used that. With a setState etc...

Comment: That's not possible. Navigation will load a new widget.

Comment: so you mean its not possible through IndexedStack

Comment: Navigation is like you handle the stack of page of your app. If you are not familiar with this important notion check :https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/

Comment: Might be looking for multiple navigators: https://medium.com/coding-with-flutter/flutter-case-study-multiple-navigators-with-bottomnavigationbar-90eb6caa6dbf

Comment: @Ninja You should post your answer I will vote up.